# Elasticsearch query, sort results by timestamp not working

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch

I am using elasticsearch.helpers.scan to query ES, from a notebook, my query:

```json
q2 = {
  "query": { "match_all": {} },
  "_source": ["timestamp"],
  "sort": [{ "timestamp": { "order": "asc" } }]
}
```

generating the results:

```
scan_generator = es_helpers.scan(es_con, query=q2, index=index_name)

items = list(itertools.islice(scan_generator, 400))
```

mapping:

```
"mappings": {"audit": {"properties": {
"timestamp": {"type": "date"},
"level": {"type": "keyword"},
"message": {"type": "text"},
"logger_name": {"type": "keyword"},},}}
```

**ES version: 7.12.1**

My doc list:

```json
[
  {
    "_index": "test1",
    "_type": "audit",
    "_id": "DhXHwYYBIMT3sBSPB-i-",
    "_score": None,
    "_source": { "timestamp": "2023-03-08T15:11:31.773837" },
    "sort": [0]
  },
  {
    "_index": "test1",
    "_type": "audit",
    "_id": "DRXEwYYBIMT3sBSPOeg-",
    "_score": None,
    "_source": { "timestamp": "2023-03-08T15:08:27.837724" },
    "sort": [0]
  },
  {
    "_index": "test1",
    "_type": "audit",
    "_id": "DBXDwYYBIMT3sBSP8Oj3",
    "_score": None,
    "_source": { "timestamp": "2023-03-08T15:08:09.334451" },
    "sort": [0]
  }
]
```

It won't sort the results, any ideas why?

Comment: Can you show your index mapping (just the timestamp field)? Also it would be helpful to see how you're querying (what client, etc)

Comment: check now, still working on this one..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [official documentation](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/v7.12.1/helpers.html#scan)

> By default scan does not return results in any pre-determined order. To have a standard order in the returned documents (either by score or explicit sort definition) when scrolling, use preserve_order=True. This may be an expensive operation and will negate the performance benefits of using scan.

So either specify `preserve_order=True` or simply use the [search endpoint](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/v7.12.1/api.html#elasticsearch.Elasticsearch.search) by [leveraging the `search_after`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/paginate-search-results.html#search-after) feature.

Comment: `preserve_order=True` + sort by timestamp does the job, thanks